# Microsoft graph api returns 403 forbidden when calling groups/xxxx/members

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I have an application calling the graph api in order to update my database of users to match the active directory users.

I see that every single user calling it is getting an error. 403 forbidden.  I did some research and saw that the user needs to grant directory.read...  so I did that and then it works.

However, I do not want to have my application request each user to grant those permissions.  I believe maybe I can accomplish the same goal by granting the right permissions to the “user” behind the application.  I am not really sure who that is.  Does maybe the secret and the client located in my web.config play into this?  The reason I think maybe yes, is because I use those credentials to initially authenticate myself to the graph api.  I do. To pass the current users Microsoft info to log in...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that scenario, you can configure the app to use App-Only permissions. In the documentation, it is referred as "Application" permission. The permissions are granted to an application. Consent is granted only once by an administrator, and users are not prompted to consent later. More: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent

Comment: Only once by one administrator from my own organization or once by each sso organization?

Comment: You'll need an administrator of each tenant to grant your application access to their tenant. This can also be integrated in the openid connect flow. Then the non-admin user gets a message that they need an Administrator to approve (and access) the application.

Comment: But this is a call to my own active directory.  Why do other admins and users need to grant any permissions?  These tenants reside in my own active directory

Comment: Where do I do this?  Somewhere in the azure portal?

Comment: @Stephan can you help me understand where to do this exactly?

Comment: @Leah you might have SSO configured in your AAD to different tenants, but the grant has to be added directly on the tenant itself (cannot be done through SSO) and it has to be done by the tenant administrator. More: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent#using-the-admin-consent-endpoint